# How to create pointer to Parse PFUser from facebook ID

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm doing a Facebook graph call to get friends of the user that are using my app. I get the facebook ID of the user's friends back from the graph call. Below is what I'm attempting to obtain from Parse with that ID, but's it's not getting all the users back, I believe since its an async call. How can I save an array of pointers of the user's fb friends that are using the app? Thanks in advance!!

```
 graphConnection.addRequest(requestFriends, completionHandler: { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                     if result.objectForKey("friends") != nil {

                        // parsing dictionary to get results
                        let firstDict = result.objectForKey("friends")
                        let dataArray = firstDict!.objectForKey("data")

                        let myFriendsUsingTheAppCount = dataArray!.count
                        print("\(myFriendsUsingTheAppCount)")

                        let friendsArray:NSMutableArray = []

                        for var i = 0; i < dataArray!.count; i++ {

                           let friend = dataArray![i]

                           let friendFbObjectID = friend.objectForKey("id")!

                           let query = PFUser.query()
                           query!.whereKey("facebookID", equalTo: friendFbObjectID)

                           query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                              if error == nil {

                                 // this is where I was going to save this specific user as a pointer

                              } else {

                                 // some error
                              }
                           })
                           // this is saving just the friend's name/fb id to an array, but I want an array of pointers to the PFUser
                           friendsArray.addObject(friend)
                        }

                     } else {

                        // fb friends is nil
                        print("FB friends came back nil")
                     }
                  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be simplified into a single query by using `whereKey:containedIn:`

```
let facebookIDs = dataArray.map { $0.objectForKey("id")! }
let query = PFUser.query()!
query.whereKey("facebookID", containedIn: facebookIDs)
```

The query will now contain all users whose facebook id is in the array passed to the query.

(swift syntax may be incorrect did not double check)